# Configuring HugePages on Google's TCMalloc

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, dynamic-memory-allocation, tcmalloc

I had earlier raised a query on the `github.com/google/tcmalloc` regarding how I can force tcmalloc to back memory with hugetlbfs instead of using Transparent Huge Pages. I have attached the link to my query below. Please let me know if there is any possible way to do this.

https://github.com/google/tcmalloc/issues/190

Note: Not to get confused with gperftools/tcmalloc ; the procedure here is rather straightforward.